# Updating eigen decomposition for a matrix after some row changes

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Let us say we have a matrix $A$ which has eigen decomposition

$$A=UDU^{-1}$$

If some of the rows of A are changed by multiplying a constant positive value, is there a simple way to update the eigen decomposition from existing $D$ and $U$?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none that I know of. What you ask about is $XA$, where $X$ is a diagonal matrix.

Note that by premultiplying $A$ with some diagonal matrix $D$, you generally lose Hermitianity/similarity/normality/... and any other nice structure that $A$ may have had.

So, while $A$ may have only real eigenvalues (for $A$ Hermitian/symmetric) or on a unit circle (for $A$ unitary/orthogonal), $XA$ can have random complex eigenvalues.

Further, when you lose normality ($A^*A = AA^*$, but $(XA)^*(XA) \ne (XA)(XA)^*$), you also lose diagonality of $D$.

Comment: Thanks Vedran. I have updated my question.

Comment: This is a completely new question, and it should be opened as such, possibly with a link to this one, but leaving this one as it was. This way, my answer is meaningless.

Comment: I moved my new question to a new post. [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534984/finding-the-inverse-of-the-sum-of-two-symmetric-matrices-ab)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.